# How do I link my games in the 3DS releases of the Oracles games?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, zelda-oracle-of-ages, zelda-oracle-of-seasons

Originally, linking the games required passwords for the most part, but you could also link using a Game Link cable to connect the games (provided you had two GameBoys to use).

Do the Virtual Console releases only work with passwords for items and rings and the like? The game still mentions using a Game Link cable, but I am assuming that is because this is a direct port of the original.

Am I stuck just remembering passwords and secrets and writing them down to enter later? Or is there any other way to link the two games?

Comment: I'm curious as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 3DS doesn't have any actual link between the two games, it's still just using the password system, to transfer back and forth your new items (sword and shield upgrades, the biggoron sword etc). Just remember that the passwords are generated on your specific game, based on where you are at in the story, what items you have, what you named Bopin and his son etc etc etc.

On the plus side, you can exit to the home screen, open the notepad and write it down now!