# How do I transfer my secrets between the original Legend of Zelda: Oracles of Ages and Seasons and the 3DS versions?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, zelda-oracle-of-seasons, zelda-oracle-of-ages

It's been a while since I played the original editions of *The Legend of Zelda: Oracle of Ages* and *Oracle of Seasons*.

I'm starting up cold on the 3DS and I want to know how to transfer all my secrets from the old games to the new ones. I haven't been having any luck transferring my main secrets password from one game to the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I link my games in the 3DS releases of the Oracles games?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118760/how-do-i-link-my-games-in-the-3ds-releases-of-the-oracles-games)

Comment: @Nolonar: I think he's asking if it's possible to link a GBC game with a 3DS version.

Comment: I see. What about the password? I doubt the password system has changed from the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the 3DS lacks any sort of capability to use the Game Link cable, the only way you could connect your old games to the new 3DS ones is by using the password system. The 3DS version seems to accept passwords and secrets the same way the original games did, so you should be able to input them with no problem, as the games are direct ports from the old cartridge versions, with no changes. (they even still mention using the Game Link cable!)

Comment: I keep getting errors when I input my password on the new game screen…

Comment: It might not be possible then, and I could be entirely wrong.

Comment: Ok, the whole thing decided to work the other day. I don't know if I was putting it in wrong or something.